# openGL limited 3D space

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm having problem with my drawing code..I have to display some arrows, but when they are too far from the origin of the axis they disappear..

Here I post my relevant code:

```
static void drawArrow( double trans[3][4] , double **d, int num, double *altitude)
{

int i;
double c_min=0.3;





double    gl_para[16];
GLfloat   mat_ambient[]     = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0};
GLfloat   mat_flash[]       = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0};
GLfloat   mat_flash_shiny[] = {50.0};
GLfloat   light_position[]  = {100.0,-200.0,200.0,0.0};
GLfloat   ambi[]            = {0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1};
GLfloat   lightZeroColor[]  = {0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.1};

...

argConvGlpara(trans, gl_para);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity
glLoadMatrixd( gl_para );

glRotated(180,1,0,0);
glutWireCone(40,40*arrow_factor,10,100);
//arrowfactor can change by keyboard input
...


glDisable( GL_LIGHTING );

glDisable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );

}
```

I suppose I have to use GL_PROJECTION matrix mode, but I belive that if there is a better way to let it work without change it at all..

EDIT: removed unnecessary parts of code

Comment: Can you reduce your code? SSCCE is best, but at least remove any call which isn't needed for the behaviour to be seen. Anyway, you may have a clip plane enabled, or you're reaching the far side of your depth map (which is being controlled by the first parameter to your function)

Comment: sorry I don't understand what clip plane and depth map are..
PS: I post all the code 'cause everytime somebody ask me to add the other part of the code..so this time i had the idea to prevent..

Comment: Think of the edges of your monitor - there are 4 clipping edges. Nothing outside of those borders will (can) be shown. A clip-plane is the 3d analogue. If something is on the other side of the plane, it won't be shown. But google will tell you this and far, far more. :p

Comment: I do not know how `argConvGlpara (...)` is implemented here, but usually you only setup the projection matrix when your window (the 2D thing you are projecting the world onto) changes dimensions. Translating, rotating, scaling, etc. individual objects is done with a separate transformation matrix (modelview). Depth range and clipping is defined by your projection matrix so this is another reason you usually do not want to mess with the matrix too much.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman argConvGlpara (...) is a function of ARToolkit libraries that change the trans_matrix from 3x4 to 1x16..

Comment: @enhzflep i tried to search on the web and I found that the function glFrustum give the chance to change the distance of the far clipping plane..but it doesn't work.. now i edit the code i tried to implement

Comment: Your ARToolkit function is setting the znear and zfar properties, which get encoded into the matrix. Try searching for OpenGL projection matrix and you'll find the equations. With that, you should be able to change the relevant part of the matrix. Or you could try finding a way to set it in ARToolkit (though it may be hard-coded).